# IP access okay but ping doesn't work

Tags: ip, ping

I have a laptop connected to a Wi-Fi, and let's say I am testing the connection to a website ("randomwebsite.com", IP:123.123.123.123)

Through a terminal I have tested ping:

```
kwagjj@kwagjj-Inspiron-3420:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.72.106) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tf-in-f106.1e100.net (173.194.72.106): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=74.0 ms
64 bytes from tf-in-f106.1e100.net (173.194.72.106): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=77.8 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 74.063/75.946/77.830/1.903 ms

kwagjj@kwagjj-Inspiron-3420:~$ ping randomwebsite.com
PING randomwebsite.com (123.123.123.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- randomwebsite.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms

kwagjj@kwagjj-Inspiron-3420:~$
```

As you can see, pinging to "www.google.com" is okay, but the ping to the "randomwebsite.com" doesn't get any response.

However, when I open my Firefox and type "randomwebsite.com" or the IP address of it, the webpage appears fine.

What can cause this ping to not work?

Comment: It's fairly common to block 'ping' traffic at a firewall, whilst still allowing 80/tcp for web server access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That server might be configured not to answer ICMP packages, or its router is set-up not to let those through.

I remember from the time I was still using Windows XP that you had to explicitly install things in order for the machine to answer `ping` packages.